Swagger OpenAPI Gives error with style simple and schema type object with path variables
I am using swagger request validator library (version 2.22.0) in my project with below yaml configurations.
info:
  title: Sample API
  version: 1.0.0
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /demo/{groupIdentifier}:
    get:
      description: This API which will provide all the members of a group.
      operationId: get-group-v2
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful response
    parameters:
    - description: Composite group identifier
      explode: false
      in: path
      name: groupIdentifier
      required: true
      allowReserved: true
      schema:
        properties:
          domainCode:
            description: Code of the master data domain
            type: string
          groupTypeCode:
            description: The prototype type of the group that has to be searched
            type: string
        type: object
      style: simple

running api gives me below error :
"oas://openapi.yaml": failed with reason: "[ERROR - Unable to parse JSON - Unrecognized token 'domainCode': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n\t at [Source: (String)"domainCode,CUSTOMER,groupTypeCode,CUSTOMER_GROUP"; line: 1, column: 11].: []]""

in the api call, I am passing path variables in object format (comma seperated) as mentioned in the doc - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/
ex. http://test.com/demo/domainCode,CUSTOMER,groupTypeCode,CUSTOMER_GROUP
Also, I debugged the library and found that its trying to convert comma-seperated values in json and hence, giving this error. can anyone please suggest whats wrong with the yaml configuration here ?
tried configuring style simple with path variables object serialization. Expecting that it should work as per the swagger official document.

Do you mean this library -- https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/? Your OpenAPI definition is correct, so this is a tooling issue/limitation. If you are the developer of the API, maybe consider switching from path parameters to query parameters (e.g. /demo?domainCode=CUSTOMER&groupTypeCode=CUSTOMER_GROUP).

Thanks @Helen for quick response. Unfortunately, changing api spec is not our my control.
I tried checking github but couldn't even find the open bug for this issue. Do you have reference of any open thread where other developers have mentioned about this issue ?
Is this resolved in new version - 2.40.0 ?

You can open an issue or search for existing issues here: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/issues
